# D2 gdc link error - undefined reference to `_D3std6stdint12__ModuleInfoZ`

Tags: d, undefined-reference, gdc

I'm using https://bitbucket.org/goshawk/gdc/downloads/gcc-4.5.2-tdm-1-gdc-r575-20110723.zip with TDM GCC 4.5.2 in -v2 mode to build a DLL. In one of the modules I do `import std.stdint`. So I thought I should link against libgphobos2 to fix this but it gives me even more errors:

```
c:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../libgphobos2.a(thread.o): In function `D4core6thread6Thread6__ctorMFZC4core6thread6Thread':
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsend'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsend'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsend'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
c:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../libgphobos2.a(thread.o): In function `thread_entryPoint@4':
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:173: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsend'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:173: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:173: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
c:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../libgphobos2.a(thread.o): In function `D4core6thread6Thread6__ctorMFZC4core6thread6Thread':
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsend'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
c:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../libgphobos2.a(thread.o): In function `thread_attachThis':
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1957: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
c:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../libgphobos2.a(thread.o): In function `D4core6thread6Thread6__ctorMFZC4core6thread6Thread':
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsend'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
c:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../libgphobos2.a(thread.o): In function `thread_attachByAddrB':
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:2048: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
c:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../libgphobos2.a(thread.o): In function `D4core6thread18thread_getTLSBlockFZAv':
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:2632: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsend'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:2632: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:2632: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
c:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../libgphobos2.a(thread.o): In function `D4core6thread6Thread6__ctorMFZC4core6thread6Thread':
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsend'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsend'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
C:\crossdev\gdc\v2\build\mingw32\libphobos/../../../gcc-4.5.2/libphobos/core/thread.d:1363: undefined reference to `__emutls_v._tlsstart'
```

Is this a bug or do I need to pass some extra flags to gdc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also experimented with GDC from bitbucket sources in -v2 mode for compiling a library, in an attempt to interface some D functionality with a C++ application.

I found the same problem with missing link to _tlsstart and _tlsend.
A partial solution is to include a "main" function in the library:

```
void main(){}
```

I'm working with a static library on linux.  I inspected the resulting static library with:

```
nm libDexample.a
```

This shows that the above trivial main inserts extra symbols into libDexample.d, (which also end up in the c++ executable):

```
_Dmain
_tlsend
_tlsstart
```

Of course, these symbols give link errors relating to multiple definitions if the library is used in a D application.  Therefore, you can define a separate library eg libtls.d containing:

```
extern(C) void make_it_link_please(){}
//inserts the _tlsstart and _tlsend stuff???????
void main()
{
}
```

Where one links with libtls in the case of a c++ application but not a D application.